Bounding of this series
Prove this series converges absolutely.
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{(x^2-7x+6)^n}{n^2 6^{n+2}}$$
Attempts
As in the comments, it doesn't say where. But I believe it's meant for $x \in (0, 3) \cup (4, 7)$ as I showed below (?)
Well I know from triangle inequality that $\bigg| \sum a_n \bigg| \leq \sum |a_n|$ and if the latter converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.
So this is what I did

$(x^2-7x+6)^n = (x-1)^n(x-6)^n$ and then I recognized the geometric part $\left(\frac{(x-1)(x-6)}{6}\right)^n$ iff $x \in (0, 3) \cup (4, 7)$.

Now:
$$\bigg|\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{(x^2-7x+6)^n}{6^{n+2}n^2}\bigg| \leq \frac{1}{36}\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \bigg| \left(\frac{(x^2-7x+6)}{6}\right)^n \bigg| \frac{1}{n^2} \bigg|  \bigg| \leq \frac{1}{36} C \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{C}{36}\cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Where I thought $C = \sup \bigg|\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{(x^2-7x+6)}{6}\right)^n\bigg|$
Question I cannot understand if this method is correct, and I cannot understand how to give an estimation for the sup. The series converges to a function that when plotted for $x \in (0, 7)$ has a minimum at $x = 7/2$ and the values is $-1/2$.
I thought to use the absolute value, hence it becomes $1/2$ and then I have $C$, but I feel like it's wrong.
Any help?

Prove that the series converges absolutely where? This definitely does not converge on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

@JulioPuerta For $x \in (0, 3) \cup (4, 6)$

@Heidegger Well, this should appear in the question. Without this, the question makes no sense.

@Mark I swear the text is only that one.. Taken from the notes I'm using

@Heidegger Maybe the question is supposed to be to find all $x$ for which it is absolutely convergent?

@Mark At this point I think the text is just ill-written. It says "prove the series is absolutely convergent". And it's specified $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Let $c=x^2-7x+6$.
Then, the series of the absolute values is $$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{|c|^n}{n^2 6^{n+2}}$$
If $|c|>6$ then $\dfrac{|c|^n}{n^26^{n+2}}\to+\infty$ and so $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{|c|^n}{n^2 6^{n+2}}$ diverges.
Now, if $|c|\leq 6$ we can bound this sequence $$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{|c|^n}{n^2 6^{n+2}}\leq\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{6^n}{n^2 6^{n+2}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{36n^2}$$
As $\displaystyle\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 }$ converges, we get that the series converges absolutely iff $$|x^2-7x+6|=|c|\leq 6\iff x\in [0,3]\cup [4,7]$$

Ahhh this is what I was missing. The bounding $|c| < 6$. Brilliant. Thank you!!

@Heidegger $\le6$, not $<6$. And it was (essentially) a multiduplicate.

@AnneBauval I don't understand the $\leq$. The series is geometric, if we let $c = 6$ it becomes divergent...

No it is not geometric (don't forget the $\frac1{n^2}$), and no it does not become divergent. Please look at the proposed duplicate target.

@AnneBauval You're right, it's not just the geometric term... Thank you again!
